# Is there a way to improve the performance of this for loop in R?

Tags: r, performance, loops

I have a dateset that has a little over 1.32 million observations. I am trying to add a "growth.factor" column to the dataset that sets a specific value given the county and classification from another dataset called "cat.growth" which is 44x8.

I need to run the following code 352 times---changing the county and classification names---to get my desired result (44 counties, 8 different classifications):

```
parcel.data.1$growth.factor <- ifelse(parcel.data.1$classification == "Ag" & parcel.data.1$county == "Ada", 1 + cat.growth["Ada","Ag"], parcel.data.1$growth.factor)
```

If I do so, it takes approximately 16.7 seconds to run. But It takes up 352 lines of code. I can achieve the same thing in 4 lines of code with this for loop:

```
for (x in parcel.data.1) {
  for (y in parcel.data.1$classification) {
    parcel.data.1$growth.factor <- ifelse(parcel.data.1$classification == y & parcel.data.1$county == x, 1 + cat.growth[x,y], parcel.data.1$growth.factor)
  }}
```

But when I run it, I cant even get it to complete (I gave up after 12 minutes). I've tried using all my cores in my Mac using:

```
library(foreach)
library(doSNOW)
c1 <- makeCluster(8, type = "SOCK")
registerDoSNOW(c1)
```

But that didn't help. I've looked at all the blogs and other posts regarding slow loops, but my code is only a single line so I didn't see anything that applied to making to faster in those other suggestions.

Any help getting this loop to run in less than a minute would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: Hi there, could you show some of the content of both files, showing how you're linking the two files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have pointed out, you shouldn't use a loop. But your question seems to be "Why is this loop taking so long?"

The answer is that you seem to be looping over all 1.36 million elements of `parcel.data.1$county` and all 1.36 million elements of `parcel.data.1$classification`. This means that your loop is evaluating `ifelse()`
`1360000^2` times, not 352 times.

If you are going to use a loop, then loop over the *unique* elements of each column, which are given by the row names and column names of `cat.growth`.

```r
for (x in rownames(cat.growth)) { # loop over counties
  for (y in colnames(cat.growth)) { # loop over classifications
    ...
  }
}
```

This loop is equivalent to your original script with 352 lines of code, so it should have roughly the same run time of ~16 seconds.

Note that if you didn't already know the unique elements of those two vectors, then you could use `unique()` to find them.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the reason joins were created, and the `dplyr` package is what you want.

I don't have your data, but based on your code, I have assembled some simple fake data that looks like it may be structured like yours.

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = c("Ag", "Ag", "Be", "Be", "Mo", "Mo"),
                  y = c("A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B"))
df2 <- data.frame(x = c("Ag", "Be", "Mo"),
                  A = c(1, 2, 3),
                  B = c(4, 5, 6))
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
  inner_join(df2 %>% pivot_longer(cols = c(A, B), names_to = "y")) %>%
  mutate(value = value + 1)
Joining, by = c("x", "y")
   x y value
1 Ag A     2
2 Ag B     5
3 Be A     3
4 Be B     6
5 Mo A     4
6 Mo B     7
```

Answer (score 0):

The loop is probably not the best way of doing this. One alternative may be to reshape the cat.growth data (44 x 8) to a data.frame with variables for county, classification and growth factor (i.e. 352 x 3) and then use "merge" on this and the original data frame.

To illustrate what I mean (based on what I understand your data looks like):

```
cat.growth <- as.data.frame(matrix(nrow = 44, ncol = 8,
                            dimnames = list(1:44, letters[1:8]),
                            data = rnorm(44*8)))

parcel.data <- data.frame(county = sample(1:44, 1e06, replace = TRUE),
                          classification = sample(letters[1:8], 1e06, replace = TRUE))

cat.growthL = reshape(cat.growth, direction = "long", 
                      idvar = "county", 
                      ids = rownames(cat.growth),
                      varying = 1:8, 
                      times = colnames(cat.growth),
                      timevar = "classification", 
                      v.names = "growth.factor")

parcel.data2 = merge(parcel.data, cat.growthL)
```

Comment: on further evaluation, this method had the quickest run time, and only added a single line of code given the other things I had to do to the data frames to achieve what I wanted to do. So I went with this solution after all. Thanks again!